# Redhat Python 2.7.6 installation on virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, installation, virtualenv, redhat

in what order should I install things? My goal is to have python 2.7.6 running on a virtualenv for a project for work. I am working on a Virtual Box machine in CentOS 6.5.

What folders should I be operating in to install things? I have never used linux before today, and was just kind of thrust into this task of getting a program running that requires python 2.7.6 and a bunch of packages for it. Thanks in advance if you can get me command line entries. I have opened about 3 Virtual Boxes and deleted them because I installed things in the wrong order. Please let me know how things should be installed, with command line entries, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Linux you don't need to worry about where to install files, the OS takes care of that for you.  Google CentOS Yum and read the Yum docs on how to install everything.  You probably already have Python 2.7 installed, to check just open the terminal CTRL + ALT + T, and type python.  This will start the python interpreter and display the version.  The next step would be to see if pip and virtualenv are installed. You can simply type the command at the command prombt (exit python first).  If you get something to the effect of command not found then you need to install them. Install pip with the Yum installer and virtualenv with pip. If everything is install then you just need to make your virtual environment, ex virtualenv name_of_directory, if the directory doesn't exist then yum will create it. And now you're done.

Comment: I get that first part. And no, it comes with 2.6.6 installed by default, which is why I apparently need to use a virtual env for something (not sure why, I was just told that I would break some functions if I overrode 2.6.6 with 2.7.6 without using a virtualenv). Now I have tried to install 2.7.6 several times not in a virtual env, and every time I install it the internet fails afterwards. As in, when I click the firefox link, it shows a loading icon for a few seconds and then just stops. Can anybody please tell me why this happens, or how I can install it properly?

Comment: Here is comprehensive how to, to install python 2.7 on CentOS.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4